# Five-metre square, five-metres square -- which is correct

Tags: grammaticality

The sentence is: Her face was displayed on a five-metre square monitor. I want the area to be five square metres. Which is correct (or are they all wrong):

```
a five-metre square monitor
a five metres square monitor
a five-metre squared monitor
```

I know I could write 'a monitor with an area of five square metres', but people often use one of the above and I would like to know which is correct and why in terms of grammatical rules.

Comment: I think the least ambiguous version would be *a five square metre display*, but even then you can bet some people would visualise a display that was five metres on a side (i.e. - ***twenty-five** square metres*), so I don't think "correct grammar" is the way to approach this one. Why not do the math yourself and work out the *diagonal* measurement of the display, since that's how we usually describe screen sizes today?

Comment: I think the problem stems from your hyphenation, which strongly suggests that *five* relates to a linear measure (which is then squared to give 25 m^2).

Comment: It is a piece of sci-fi and so things like screen ratio are not really relevant. I was wondering whether there was an explanation in terms of compound adjectives or something along those lines.

Comment: Arguably in your context it doesn't matter too much whether the reader simply thinks of (at least two) sides being 5 metres, or tries to visualise (in whatever aspect ratio he might expect) a display covering five square metres in total. Perhaps you could use some "quantifier" that was more "familiar, accessible" to the average person, such as *a screen as tall as a person*.

Comment: @BrianDonovan how do you get a length in square units? Surely it's an area?

Comment: It seems to me that Laurel has pointed to the answer. I did search the site, but I didn't use the right terms to find this answer. Thank you for all the comments.